# **How to Count the Occurrences of a value by referring a particular name in referring next sheet excel**

Tags: excel-formula

[![how to count the occurences of a value by referring a particular name referring next sheet][1]][1]

Hi Guys, 
My requirement is, in sheet1 I have two columns one containing names and second is numbers (Names may be recurring and there are constant values also recurring)

```
Name                   Number
arumugam rajagopal      0:05
arumugam rajagopal      0:15
arumugam rajagopal      0:02
arumugam rajagopal      0:15
arumugam rajagopal      0:02
gandhi sangita          0:10
gandhi sangita          0:05
gandhi sangita          0:05
gandhi sangita          0:05
```

In my sheet 2

```
Name\Time           0:02        0:05         0:10            0:15         
arumugam rajagopa   ?           ?              ?              ?
gandhi sangita      ?           ?               ?              ?
```

I want to write a formula which fills in the number of times the value has recurred for a particular username and for the particular number.

I am stuck please guide me in this process.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are there any formulas you have already tried? Please try and provide any code/work you have done so far in order to receive the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear on what you are asking but I think `SUMPRODUCT` is what will work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$50="arumugam rajagopal")*(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$50="0:15"))
```

This will add all occurrences where the name is arumugam rajagopal and the number is 0:15 looking in the first 50 rows. You can change it to fit your needs. Also, you may need to lose the quotes around `"0:15"` depending on how you have the cell formatted. The quotes reference a string and not a number.

Change the number for each value you need to search and put the equation in the appropriate cell.

Answer (score 0):

The COUNTIFS function will do this.

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,B$1)
```

This function allows you to specify multiple ranges and criteria.

In this case, Sheet1 column A has the criteria of matching the name in Sheet2 column A, and Sheet1 column B has the criteria of matching the number in the first row of Sheet 2.